# Self-created desktop.ini does not work

Tags: windows-7, desktop.ini

In Windows 7 x64 SP1, when creating a **desktop.ini** file with a text editor (e.g. notepad, notepad++) and saving it inside a folder, it does not work. For example, I have saved this desktop.ini inside a folder:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=C:\Windows\explorer.exe,0
[ViewState]
Mode=
Vid=
FolderType=Generic
```

But it does not work, i.e. the folder icon does not change! I have tried ANSI or Unicode encoding, neither does work.

Of course, when I change the folder icon with the Properties dialog, it does work: The folder shows the new icon and the desktop.ini file is created inside the folder with exactly the above format.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **desktop.ini** should have the **attribute of system**, and the folder containing it also needs to have the attribute of system for it to have an effect.

Use the [following procedure to customize a folder's style with Desktop.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

- Use PathMakeSystemFolder to make the folder a system folder. This sets the read-only bit on the folder to indicate that the special behavior reserved for Desktop.ini should be enabled. You can also make a folder a system folder from the command line by using **attrib +s FolderName**.
- Create a Desktop.ini file for the folder. **You should mark it as hidden and system** to ensure that it is hidden from normal users.
- Make sure the Desktop.ini file that you create is in the **Unicode format**. This is necessary to store the localized strings that can be displayed to users.

Comment: Thanks! I only changed the attributes of the desktop.ini to system and hidden. I didn't know that also the folder needs the system attribute. Now it works! Thanks again!

Comment: However the desktop.ini created by Windows with the Properties dialog is encoded in ANSI, not in Unicode. See this screenshot from notepad++ http://i.imgur.com/xLtzQ7G.png

Comment: @user1580348: Yes, this is ONLY necessary to store the localized strings e.g. Arabic or Chinese.

Comment: Hi duDE, is it possible to add custom sections with name-value pairs to the desktop.ini file, or would this conflict with the normal operation? The reason is: In addition to the folder-icon functionality, I want to store other custom information in this file.

Comment: Try it out, I would say it's possible ...

Comment: Of course I've already tried it out and it seems to not conflict with normal operation. However, this could be different in the long-term. That's why I asked - it could be that somebody knows it better. That's why people ask questions here. No need to vote something down because someone asks a question...

Comment: The corrent encoding of desktop.ini should be UTF-8, to be exact!

Comment: Actually, only the system attribute for the containing folder is required. Everything else is unneeded in most cases.

Comment: Using Windows 11, I have found that the folder need the readonly attribute set, not system. `attrib +r folder`. This is what the GUI methods seems to do as well.

Comment: If containing folder gets read-only state, doesn't that mean it can't be written to (by user), or re-written (as in changing its name or likewise)? Are there any consequences having a folder attrib as +r? And what does system folder mean?

Comment: This is wrong. The `desktop.ini` file needs `+s`, the folder needs `+r`. It was like that already with Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very easy way to set the relevant attributes for the folder and its `desktop.ini` simply using Explorer.

1. Create the `desktop.ini` file and save it in the top level of the folder. If you are using Notepad or something similar, make sure to save it as type "All Files" so that it does not save as `desktop.ini.txt`. The encoding is not important if you are not using any special characters.
2. Click `Properties` in the folder's right-click menu and open the `Customize` tab.*
3. Click `OK` (not `Cancel` or the X in the corner). There is no need to change any settings.

The folder's and `desktop.ini`'s attributes have now been automatically set. The folder's displayed icon also refreshes immediately, without requiring deleting `iconcache.db` or restarting the computer. This also causes `desktop.ini` to disappear if Explorer is set to hide protected operating system files.

I have verified that this method works on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

**If you can't see the `Customize` tab, try right clicking the folder and then clicking `Open Folder Location`, then proceeding.*