# How do I create a missing desktop.ini file

Tags: windows-7, desktop.ini

Windows 7 Home Premium x64
My desktop.ini file in c:\Users\username\Desktop is missing.  This occurred after cloning of a HDD to SSD.

There is a Desktop file in the folder but it is a link.

How do I create the missing desktop.ini file?

Thanks

John M

Comment: What problem are you trying to by to solve it can possibly be just creating a desktop.in file.  [The file can be create manually.](https://superuser.com/questions/882442/self-created-desktop-ini-does-not-work?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks.  What do I include in the file?  I don't know what should be included.

Comment: I have no idea what your trying to do.  If the file is missing then it was deleted, if it was deleted it will automatically be recreated, when it's needed.

Comment: Thank you.  I was under the impression that I had to create one as it was missing.